# Group and average dataframe rows based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
Company_ID  Year   Metric_1  Metric_2  Bankrupt
1           2010   10        20        0.0
1           2011   NaN       30        0.0
1           2012   30        40        0.0
1           2013   50        NaN       1.0
2           2012   50        60        0.0
2           2013   60        NaN       0.0
2           2014   10        10        0.0
3           2011   100       100       1.0
```

What I would like to do is for each company make the average of every metric of all the years except the last year. It should only do the average of present values and ignore missing values (NaN). Also it should not average Bankrupt column.

So output should look something like this:

```
Company_ID  Year        Metric_1  Metric_2  Bankrupt
1           2010-2012   20        30        0.0
1           2013        50        Nan       1.0
2           2012-2013   55        60        0.0
2           2014        10        10        0.0
3           2011        100       100       1.0
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This way is similar to the method of [@Stef](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62347996/9274732) but I leave this one as it would work on any number of column Metric (as long as their names start with Metric). If you end up using this solution, please accept them solution instead.

You can do it like this

```
#mask for catching last year per Company
m = df.groupby(['Company_ID'])['Year'].transform('max').eq(df['Year'])
# create groups per company without the last year
gr = df[~m].groupby(df['Company_ID'], as_index=False)

df_ = (pd.concat([gr.agg(Company_ID=('Company_ID', 'first'), #perform agg depending on needs
                         Bankrupt=('Bankrupt', 'first'), #here I'm not sure with value you want
                         Year=('Year', lambda x: f'{x.min()}-{x.max()}')), 
                  gr[df.filter(like='Metric').columns].mean()], 
                 axis=1)
         .append(df[m]) # append last year
         .sort_values(['Company_ID'])
         .reset_index(drop=True)
      )
print (df_)   
   Company_ID  Bankrupt       Year  Metric_1  Metric_2
0           1       0.0  2010-2012      20.0      30.0
1           1       1.0       2013      50.0       NaN
2           2       0.0  2012-2013      55.0      60.0
3           2       0.0       2014      10.0      10.0
4           3       1.0       2011     100.0     100.0
```

Another version to avoid the append and sort_values, you can do it with a different lambda function for the Year column

```
#mask for catching last year per Company
m = df.groupby(['Company_ID'])['Year'].transform('max').eq(df['Year']) #same
# create groups per company without the last year
gr = df.groupby([df['Company_ID'], m]) #m is in the groupby and not as mask

df_ = (pd.concat([gr.agg(Company_ID=('Company_ID', 'first'), 
                        Bankrupt=('Bankrupt', 'first'),
                        Year=('Year', lambda x: f'{x.min()}-{x.max()}' if x.min()!=x.max()
                                                else x.max())), #different lambda function
                  gr[df.filter(like='Metric').columns].mean()], 
                 axis=1)
         #no more append/sort_values
         .reset_index(drop=True)
      )
```

Comment: your expression for `m` looks more elegant than mine, avoiding the lambda, +1

Answer (score 4):

```
m = df.Bankrupt.eq(0) & df.groupby('Company_ID').Year.transform(lambda x: x != x.max())
df[m].groupby(['Company_ID','Bankrupt']).agg(Year=('Year', lambda x: f'{x.min()}-{x.max()}'),
    Metric_1=('Metric_1', 'mean'),
    Metric_2=('Metric_2', 'mean')).reset_index().append(df[~m]).sort_values('Company_ID')
```

Result:

```
    Company_ID  Bankrupt       Year  Metric_1  Metric_2
0           1       0.0  2010-2012      20.0      30.0
3           1       1.0       2013      50.0       NaN
1           2       0.0  2012-2013      55.0      60.0
6           2       0.0       2014      10.0      10.0
7           3       1.0       2011     100.0     100.0
```

Comment: @Ben.T: yes, I forgot to exclude last year

Comment: @Ben.T: should be OK now, though not 100 % sure if I understood all conditions correctly

Comment: @Ben.T: Bankrupt is included in groupby just for convencience to retain this column, there's no grouping as all values are 0 as per mask condition

Answer (score 2):

Another way, very similar to others but with an additional group and without a mask:

```
#helper group
g = df.groupby(['Company_ID'])['Year'].transform(lambda x: (x.max()==x).cumsum())
#helper function
f = lambda x: f"{x.min()}-{x.max()}" if len(set(x))>1 else x

(df.groupby(['Company_ID',g]).agg({'Year':f,'Metric_1':'mean','Metric_2':'mean',
 'Bankrupt':'first'}).droplevel(1).reset_index())
```

---

```
   Company_ID       Year  Metric_1  Metric_2  Bankrupt
0           1  2010-2012      20.0      30.0       0.0
1           1       2013      50.0       NaN       1.0
2           2  2012-2013      55.0      60.0       0.0
3           2       2014      10.0      10.0       0.0
4           3       2011     100.0     100.0       1.0
```

Comment: Nice, actually using `dict` instead of named tuple in the agg makes it a bit easier to read and expand to more metrics columns

Comment: @Ben.T yes agreed , we didnt need a named tuple since there was no renaming :)